# Convert datetime to different format

Tags: sql, datediff

I am using the datediff function and it doesn't seem to be working. It just gives an empty result in the data extension.

What I am currently using

```
DATEDIFF(year, creation_date__c, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) AS AnniversaryYears
```

creation_date__c is of the following format: Monday, December 05, 2016 12:00 AM

So when doing this online on w3schools it seems to work:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, PARSE(‘Monday, December 05, 2016 12:00 AM’ AS datetime), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) AS DateDiff;
```

But when using the parse function with creation_date__c it gives the following error: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of parse function.

Any idea on how to parse it or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used there...)

Comment: What database engine are you using? (Hint: SQL = "Structured Query Language". If you're using MS SQL Server, please tag the question appropriately).

Comment: "`creation_date__c`is of the following format".  Excuse me.  Why are you not using built-in data types for date/time.  Fix your data and your code will work.

Comment: This is the query language within Salesforce Marketing Cloud. Gordon, this is the standard data type in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to Parse a datetime to a datetime, please see the fix below. In SSMS I get the same output from both statements. To use PARSE(variable as DATETIME) you need to have a variable that is of a type that can be converted to DATETIME.

```
DECLARE @creation_date__c  VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Monday, December 05, 2016 12:00 AM' ; 

SELECT DATEDIFF(year, PARSE(@creation_date__c as datetime), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) AS 
DateDiff
```